# Unsupported engine for got@5.7.1

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Trying to install npm packages and i'm getting this error:

```
1 error generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Volumes/Work/Click-Quell-Theraputics/web/app/themes/quell-theme/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/16.11.1/bin/node" "/Volumes/Work/Click-Quell-Theraputics/web/app/themes/quell-theme/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /Volumes/Work/Click-Quell-Theraputics/web/app/themes/quell-theme/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v16.11.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for got@5.7.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.0 <7"} (current: {"node":"16.11.1","npm":"6.14.8"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: got@5.7.1
npm WARN stylelint-webpack-plugin@0.10.5 requires a peer of webpack@^1.13.2 || ^2.7.0 || ^3.11.0 || ^4.4.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ajv-keywords@2.1.1 requires a peer of ajv@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.12.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.12.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I always seem to have issues with node sass, but i'm not really sure what this is telling me is wrong?

One line that sticks out is this: "Unsupported engine for got@5.7.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.0 <7"} (current: {"node":"16.11.1","npm":"6.14.8"})"

Is that asking me to have node < 7 ? surely it can't be! How old must that be? That would cause problems with other projects that need a newer version.

Comment: No it is asking you to have a node greater or equal 0.10.0 and less then 7.0. So the newest you could have is 6.x.

Comment: Yeh i just edited it, but installing that version would break other projects that need the latest version.

Comment: Then you'll need to upgrade `got` (or whatever requires `got`).

Comment: The latest version of got is 11.8.2, 5.7.1 was released 5 years ago. But if you really need to run it I would suggest you install Node Version Manager (nvm) to easly switch between versions.

Comment: What is got? That isn't even in the package.json

Comment: Try `npm why got` or `yarn why got` (depending on which package manager you're using).

Comment: @AKX that didn't do anything except output npm help

Comment: Sorry, try `npm ls got` or `npm explain got` (I'm a Yarn user myself, so I forget the `npm` commands). That might show you the tree.

Comment: I actually downgrade node, and it sort of worked but another package wants the latest npm, my god! This is the Quell crappy wordpress theme btw. A way over complicated wp theme!